# javascript equivalent of python's compile and exec

Tags: javascript, python, compilation, exec, eval

In python, one can take a string containing python code, compile it and run the resulting code with exec.

Can something similar be done with javascript (any implementation is good). My objective is to get something like javascript's eval but faster.

Thank you

Comment: There's `eval()` and nothing else.

Comment: @HennyH `ast` is a Python module. This question is about JavaScript.

Comment: Quite seriously, making your own implementation of `eval()` in JavaScript will be (much) slower, both in development and running speed, except if it's for some specific niche thing that can be done without the use of `eval()` or a hand-made version of the native function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the dynamic nature of javascript, you can't really easily compile it to a lower-level language. That's why spidermonkey, V8 etc are just-in-time (JIT) compilers - they use runtime type information to partially compile fragments, sometimes more efficiently than an ahead-of-time compiler would.

Maybe you want to check out the closure compiler? https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/

Answer (score 0):

JS `eval()` is similar to Python function `eval()`. Using `eval()`, we can use HTML and JS together to create very simple JavaScript editor as the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Editor</title>
<script>
function runCode() {
   var code = document.getElementById('txtCode').value;
   eval(code);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id = "txtCode" cols = "50" rows = "5">alert("hello");</textarea>
<input type = "button" value = "Run" onClick="runCode();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

If you copy and paste the code above and run it, it would produce the alert of "hello" in the browser. You can change the code in the text area with your JavaScript code.